# com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream..............How to solve

Tags: mongodb, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

Sorry for my long post of code. 
But I am just a beginner. I want to learn Spring Framework with MongoDB.

I am getting this exception but I have read some post about this problem. However, I didn't understand and how to fix it.

I haven't created application configuration. Is this the one that causes the exception?
Can anyone help me to fix this?
I am really appreciate it. Many thanks....

```
package com.mywebapp.dao;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.mywebapp.model.Location;
import com.mywebapp.model.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<User, String>{

    List<User> findAllUsers();
    User findBy_id(ObjectId id);
    User findByUsername(String username);
    List<User> findByFirstName(String firstName);
    List<User> findByLastName(String lastName);
    User findByEmail(String email);
    List<User> findByDateOfBirth(Date dob);
    List<User> findByLocation(Location location);
}

    package com.mywebapp.controller;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.mywebapp.model.Location;
import com.mywebapp.model.User;
import com.mywebapp.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getAllUser(){
        return userService.findAllUsers();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/{username}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUserByUserName(@PathVariable("username") String userName){
        return userService.findByUserName(userName);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{firstname}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getUserByFirstName(@PathVariable("firstname") String firstName){
        return userService.findByFirstName(firstName);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{lastname}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getUserByLastName(@PathVariable("lastname") String lastName){
        return userService.findByLastName(lastName);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{email}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUserByEmail(@PathVariable("email") String email){
        return userService.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @RequestMapping(value="/{dob}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getUserByDOB(@PathVariable("dob") String dob) throws Exception{
        Date dateOfBirth = new Date(dob);
        return userService.findByDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{location}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getUserByLocation(@PathVariable("location") Location location){
        return userService.findByLocation(location);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable("id") ObjectId id) {
        return userService.findById(id);
    }

}

    package com.mywebapp.service;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.mywebapp.dao.UserRepository;
import com.mywebapp.model.Location;
import com.mywebapp.model.User;

@Service
public class UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepo;

    public UserService() {

    }

    public List<User> findAllUsers() {
        return userRepo.findAllUsers();
    }

    public User findById(ObjectId id) {
        return userRepo.findBy_id(id);
    }

    public User findByUserName(String username){
        return userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    }

    public List<User> findByFirstName(String firstName){
        return userRepo.findByFirstName(firstName);
    }

    public List<User> findByLastName(String lastName){
        return userRepo.findByLastName(lastName);
    }

    public User findByEmail(String email){
        return userRepo.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public List<User> findByDateOfBirth(Date dob){
        return userRepo.findByDateOfBirth(dob);
    }

    public List<User> findByLocation(Location location){
        return userRepo.findByLocation(location);
    }
}


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyWebApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MyWebApplication</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>10</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers!

Answer (score 0):

Define below properties in `application.properties` under resources folder, replace actual values from yours. If MongoDB is default installed and there is no user name/ password then you don't need to define username and password properties.

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=*********
spring.data.mongodb.password=*********
spring.data.mongodb.database=demo
```

**Update**

1. Update repository to extend MongoRepository

   ```
   @Repository
   public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, ObjectId> 
   {
   ```
2. Remove `List<User> findAllUsers();` from your repository.
3. Change all method in your service to below

   ```
   public List<User> findAllUsers() {
       return userRepo.findAll();
   }
   ```

Comment: please show me your document class: com.mywebapp.model.User; and error you are seeing at starting app or any specific method called??

Comment: @TyMinh check my updated answer and make sure you have some records in your user document..